# rails db:create を実行するとエラー: Could not find mysql2-0.5.4 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, docker

`rails db:create` でデータベースを作成しようとしたら以下のエラーが表示された。

```
Could not find mysql2-0.5.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

mysqlのv5.4を設定するのでしょうか？
homebrewで対応しているものを `brew search mysql` で探してみますと以下の通りです。

```
automysqlbackup             mysql-client@5.7            mysql@5.6
mysql ✔                     mysql-connector-c++         mysql@5.7 ✔
mysql++                     mysql-sandbox               mysqltuner
mysql-client                mysql-search-replace        qt-mysql
```

現在の状況は以下の通りです。mysqlのversion5.4が見つからないのでよろしくお願いします

```
brew search mysql@5.7
=> Formulae
mysql@5.7 ✔                               mysql@5.6
```

追記。
`bundle install`と`bundle update`は実行しました。

---

Docker 関連のファイルについては以下の通りです。

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  data:

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/rails-docker-mysql"
    environment:
      - "DATABASE_PASSWORD=password"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "data:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: db
  user: root
  port: 3306
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PASSWORD") %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_docker_mysql_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_docker_mysql_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_docker_mysql_production
  username: rails_docker_mysql
  password: <%= ENV['RAILS_DOCKER_MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: ログを省略せずにすべて貼ってみてください

Comment: @nekketsuuu ログとはどこの箇所ですか？

Comment: `rails db:create` 実行時に表示されるのは、質問中の1行のみでしょうか？他にも表示されているようであれば、すべてを追記してください。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 了解です。追加しました

Comment: `bundle install` は成功していますか？　ログを見て、何かしらの gem のインストールに失敗していないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql2 gem のバージョン 0.5.4 が無いというエラーです。Homebrew は関係ありません。

`bundle install` はしたとのことなので、おそらく `bundle exec rails db:create` したらエラーが出なくなるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 実行しましたが、同じエラーが出ました